# PHP SQL Serial No Between, If matching show OK, if not, show Not Matching

Tags: php

I want to ask you about validation using SQL between.

Example I have :

Serial No From : 150000
Serial No To : 185000

Now I want to make a validation if Serial No from > 150000 and Serial No To < 185000 then OK, if not, not match.

SQL

```
$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT de_no, ser_s, ser_e FROM t_product_revision WHERE ser_s > '150000' AND ser_e < '185000' && de_no = '$combine_part'");

if($sql_check)
{
echo 'OK';
}
else
{
echo 'Not match';
}
```

I just want to make validation from here, If Serial No matching with data in table, then show it OK, if not, Not match.

Any advice ?

Comment: use mysql_num_rows($sql_check) to check the result in database table

Comment: You forgot to call `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns false on _failure_, not when no rows are returned, which is not an error state.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Thanks for advice, any example for that ? :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT de_no, ser_s, ser_e FROM t_product_revision WHERE ser_s > '150000' AND ser_e < '185000' && de_no = '$combine_part'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($sql_check);

if($row>0)
{
echo 'OK';
}
else
{
echo 'Not match';
}
```

I hope it will help